# About the sequence $a_{(n+1)} = a_n + \frac{(a_n)^2}{2}$,

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence or real numbers, such that $a_1= 2$ and for every $n \geq 1$, $$a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{a_n^2}{2}$$

Evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2 + a_n}$.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to MSE. Here's a tip: everytime you want to write math things, insert then between two $. The site will format to math style. Also, searching on Google for "mathjax commands" will give you a list of commands you can use to formulate all your "math text". You may edit this post already to test it. By the way, I'm thinking for a solution to your problem.

Comment: I have voted to close this Question. Although it asks to solve a problem that admits a mathematically reasoned solution, it lacks required [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).  *Context* can be supplied in many ways and need not be an exhaustive explication of why you are interested in the problem or how it is difficult or challenging.  I'm personally inclined to accept *de minimus* information (typically "what did you try" but this is not usually the best context for Readers to grasp your point of view).

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_n = 1+\dfrac{a_n}{2}$. One notice first that
$$b_{n+1} = 1 + \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{2} = 1+\dfrac{a_n}{2} + \dfrac{a_n^2}{4} = b_n + (b_n-1)^2 = b_n^2 -b_n +1$$

Therefore,
\begin{align*} \dfrac{1}{1-b_{n+1}}-\dfrac{1}{1-b_n} & = \dfrac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{(1-b_{n+1})(1-b_n)}  = \dfrac{b_n^2 -2b_n +1}{(b_n-b_n^2)(1-b_n)}  = \dfrac{b_n-1}{b_n^2-b_n}  = \dfrac{1}{b_n} 
\end{align*}

which gives directly
$$\dfrac{1}{1-b_{n+1}}-\dfrac{1}{1-b_n} = \dfrac{2}{2+a_n}$$Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Maybe write as $\frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{a_n + 2} = \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}$ is more straightfoward